# Collect data and make response SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I just started to learn SailsJS and I ran into the following problem:

In the UserController I've got following method:

```
  /**
   * `UserController.create()`
   */
  create: function (req, res) {

    var d = {};

    c = {'fullname' : 'Sergiu Pirlici'}

    User.findOne(c, function(err, found) {
      d.found = found;
    });

    User.destroy(c, function(err){
      d.destroyed = !err;
    });

    if(req.method == 'GET') {
      res.view(d);
    }
    else if(req.method == 'POST') {

      var dat = req.params.all();

      User.create(dat, function(err, created){
        d.err = err;
        if(!err) {
          d.created = created;
        }
      });

    }

    d.foo = true;

    res.json(d);
  },
```

In variable `d` I want to collect data and pass it to view or send as JSON.

But in the value of `d` is `{'foo': true}`.

I understant that this happens because precedent actions are asynchronous.

Is there an another way to collect data and pass it to response?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a service http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Services
then pass a callback parameter.

so on the UserService.js

```
module.exports = {
    FindOne: function(cb){
        User.findOne(c, function(err, found) {
              cb(found);
            }); 
    }

};
```

then on your controller:

```
UserService.FindOne(function(found){
    //other logic
    var d = { result : found } ;
    res.json(d);
});
```